# How to remove a user's name from list of users on Windows 10 Pro lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

During maintenance, we occasionally have a need to log in to some of our users' desktops. Afterwards, some of our users get very confused when they see one of our names as the default login name and have to click "Other User" in order to proceed. This is especially true for users to use a biometric device to authenticate themselves (These users tend to forget their login.) Even if we click "Other User" for them, our name remains on the list on the bottom left which still leads to confusion.

So: Is there a way to remove the recent network user's name from the login screen on Windows 10 Pro?

Comment: Slap a paper sticky note on the monitor with brief instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. On the server that manages Group Policy, make a Group Policy Object and edit it. Go to **Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options**.

Look for the option **Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in** and set it to **Enabled**.

Group Policy will update on the computers when they restart, but you can manually do it in CMD with **GPUPDATE /FORCE**.